# Importing arbitrary per vertex information with a model

Tags: python, mesh, export, import

I am working with some models from a game (Treasure Planet Battle at Procyon), which have their own proprietary binary format (.mdb). I have managed to decode it to some extent, and export the vertices, faces and textures to a Wavefront .obj file, which I can import to Blender.

The models, however, also have lighting or shading information, which consists of two numbers, ranging between -pi and pi, and -pi/2 and pi/2, and the transparency. These three values are defined for each vertex.

I can write this information in the wavefront format as additional coordinates after the x y z coordinates.

Is it possible to modify the Wavefront import (and export) scripts to import and retain this information for each vertex, and be able to export it again.

Comment: On the blender side could store in a vertex color layer or in 3 float layers. Sure copy the obj importer / exporter and edit in changes. Where you're at would consider cutting out the obj middle man and import directly to blender.

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: For anyone else looking for the import script, it's in `scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/import_obj.py` (at least in v2.90).